# How to use geth.aar on Android mobile?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-invocation, android

I downloaded go-ethereum .aar file from here :

https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/

For my Android phone for invoking functions of my smart contract.

But I don't know how to use this file?

Comment: AAR: Android ARchive is similar to JAR with added functionality. Unlike JAR files, AAR files can contain Android resources and a manifest file, which allows you to bundle in shared resources like layouts and drawable in addition to Java classes and methods. -- What did you want to do with this file?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34241411/extract-code-from-aar-file-android **or** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24506648/adding-local-aar-files-to-gradle-build-using-flatdirs-is-not-working/28816265#28816265 ?

Answer (score 1):

you should have an IDE. Recommended is official - [AndroidStudio](https://developer.android.com/studio/). Once you have this you should:
1) Open up the project structure by right-clicking on your project and choosing “Open Module Settings” or choosing “File” > “Project Structure…”
2) Click the “+” button in the top left to add a new module.
3) Choose “Import .JAR or .AAR Package” and click the “Next” button.

from this point you should use the module/package services/API